# how to get entire table data using dynamodb scan operation in node.js

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

Table name: users
no. of rows : 100000

How can I get all records using scan operation with the help of node.js.

```
var params = {
    TableName:"users"};

docClient.scan(params, (error, result) => {
    if (error) {
      console.log('error', error);
    } else {
      console.log(result.Items); // x items
    }
});
```

but its shows part of data only. not entire table data.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the [eachPage](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/Request.html#eachPage-property) function on the request.

```
docClient.scan(params).eachPage((err, data, done) => { ... })
```

You can also use the lastEvaluatedKey you get from the results of one scan as the exclusiveStartKey for the next. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Query.html#Query.Pagination

Comment: I tried  docClient.scan(params).eachPage((err, data, done) => {console.log(data_;} //// it show 2892 rows and lastEvaluatedKey
Count: 2892,
  ScannedCount: 2892,
  LastEvaluatedKey: { device_id: 1451 }

Comment: You have to call `done` when you are done processing that page. Or you can omit the done parameter from the function e.g. `(err, data) => {...}` and api calls will be made immediately.

Comment: docClient.scan(params).eachPage((err, data, done) => {console.log(done); }                     //output:             function (result) {
        if (result === false) return;

        if (response.hasNextPage()) {
          response.nextPage().on('complete', wrappedCallback).send();
        } else {
          callback.call(response, null, null, AWS.util.fn.noop);
        }
      }// where and  how can I use lastEvaluatedKey

Comment: try `docClient.scan(params).eachPage((err, data, done) => {console.log(data); done(); }`

Comment: Its working.. thank you I try,`var count = 0;
docClient.scan(params).eachPage((err, data, done) => {
    if (data != null) {
        for (let index = 0; index < data.Items.length; index++) {
            const element = data.Items[index];
            count++;
            console.log("TOTAL::> " + count + " ITEM::> " + index + " DATA:: " + JSON.stringify(element));
        }
    }
    done();
});`

Comment: Followup question:  I had the same problem and had to use eachPage.  However, I also have a task that I need to do with I'm done processing all the records.  I tried checking the return value of the done() callback when I call it, but it is never true (in spite of doc's claim).  I also tried catching the .on('success', ...) and .on('complete', ...) events, but they are called before eachPage is called even once.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Answer to followup, which I just discovered.   Once it is done, it seems to call eachPage one more time with a null data.  I had tested for null just for good hygiene, so I didn't notice it happening.

Answer (score 4):

```
var docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();
var params = {
    TableName: "tableName"
};
var count = 0;
docClient.scan(params).eachPage((err, data, done) => {
    if (data != null) {
        for (let index = 0; index < data.Items.length; index++) {
            const element = data.Items[index];
            count++;
            console.log("TOTAL::> " + count + " ITEM::> " + index + " DATA:: " + JSON.stringify(element));
        }
    }
    done();
});
```